# Comparar matrices y crear una nueva con los elementos sobrantes en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array

El caso, tengo una matriz de 4 X 24 llamada "compara" y otra de 4 X 5 llamada "combaux".
Mi intención es comparar y eliminar de la matriz "compara" las lineas que sean iguales a las que hay en la matriz "combaux" y obtener al final una matriz 4 X 19.

un ejemplo de matrices serían:

```
compara = [
  [40.,700.,20.,70.03],
  [40.,700.,40.,60.42],
  [40.,800.,20.,78.06],
]

combaux= [
  [40.,700.,40.,60.42]
]
```

el código que me da problemas es:

```
for sub_array_combaux in combaux:
    for sub_array_compara in compara:
        if sub_array_combaux == sub_array_compara:
            compara.remove(sub_array_compara)
```

y el error que recibo en la linea del if es:

The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Bienvenido Didac Alvarez, por favor, edita tu pregunta para incluir el código que has intentado en vez de ponerlo en los comentarios.

Comment: Sin embargo, si lo pruebo en "https://repl.it/languages/python3", el código funciona perfectamente.

Comment: En el código original ambas matrices son del tipo "numpy.ndarray"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede usar la función `set` para comparar.

Es necesario recorrer y convertir las listas internas en tuplas para utilizar la función `set`:

```
compara = set(tuple(row) for row in compara) - set(tuple(row) for row in combaux)
```

El final es como sigue:

```
compara = [
  [40.,700.,20.,70.03],
  [40.,700.,40.,60.42],
  [40.,800.,20.,78.06],
]

combaux= [
  [40.,700.,40.,60.42]
]


compara = set(tuple(row) for row in compara) - set(tuple(row) for row in combaux)
print list(compara)
```

retultado:

```
[(40.0, 700.0, 20.0, 70.03), (40.0, 800.0, 20.0, 78.06)]
```

Comment: funciona, muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Te incluyo otra solución propuesta [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames) con Pandas, puesto que veo en esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/304245/como-extraer-columnas-ordenadas-de-una-matriz-tipo-set), que con los sets te está dando problemas.

```
import pandas as pd

compara = pd.DataFrame([
    [40., 700., 20., 70.03],
    [40., 700., 40., 60.42],
    [40., 800., 20., 78.06],
])

combaux = pd.DataFrame([
    [40., 700., 40., 60.42]
])

excluidos = pd.concat([compara, combaux]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

print(excluidos)
```

Esto te devolverá un dataframe así:

```
      0      1     2      3
0  40.0  700.0  20.0  70.03
2  40.0  800.0  20.0  78.06
```